# "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function." keeps popping

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview which takes datasource from a datatable
one of the columns is an int

i wish the program to display an error whenever the user tries to enter a string into that column

i add this to the DataError event

```
   private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect data type was entered");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

First of all the messagebox shows up twice in a row instead of just once
Secondly i get an irritating error after the 2 messageboxes:
Unhandled Exception with the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid because it
>   results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.